# é possível trocar de site a cada determinado tempo na mesma aba sem usar a tag iframe?

Tags: javascript, html5

Exemplo de alternância de sites com tag iframe


  
    
  

    function alternarSites() {
      
        const iframe = document.getElementById('myframe');
        const sites = [
            'https://sistemas.usb.org.br',
            'https://www.wikipedia.org',
            'https://www.sporcle.com',
            'https://www.radio.garden',
            'https://www.freerice.com',
        ];

          
        let index = 0;
        setInterval(() => {
            iframe.src = sites[index];
            index = (index + 1) % sites.length;
        }, 5000);
    }

    alternarSites();

Comment: Desde que todos os sites sejam seus, sim. Mas é bom uma lida na [help] para entender melhor que tipo de pergunta é esperada nesse site. Caso tenha como elaborar para que sua dúvida caia no escopo do site, queira [restaurar e editar sua pergunta original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/581692/70) que ela entra numa reavaliação. Para evitar descentralização de informações, o campo de comentários foi desativado aqui, mas pode ser utilizado na primeira postagem, se restaurada. (caso tenha alguma dificuldade para restaurar, sinalize para atenção da moderação)